# How can I debug a language server crash on launch

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

I can debug the client, which causes the launch of an extension host. Before I have the luxury of attaching a debugger to the server the host tell's me "The Language Server Example server crashed 5 times in the last 3 minutes. The server will not be restarted."

Any clues or insight into how I might get some diagnostics, logs anything would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `--debug-brk=3456` to the debugOptions, 3456 being the port on which you want to connect the language server debugger.
This forces the language client to wait until debugging was started for the language server.